How to calculate dynamic range gap on a dynamic slider so min/max values dont overlap?
I'm using this double range slider as an example(https://jsfiddle.net/ogvntk1z/).
The min/max handler values of the double ranger are dynamic. I need to make the rangeGap distance dynamic too. and not set to a constant value 50000
I'm struggling to calculate the rangeGap between min/max handlers


const progressBar = document.querySelector('.slider--progress');
const inputRange = document.querySelectorAll('.slider--input');

let rangeGap = 50000;

inputRange.forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
    let minValue = parseInt(inputRange[0].value);
    let maxValue = parseInt(inputRange[1].value);
    if (maxValue - minValue < rangeGap) {
      if (e.target.classList.contains('input--min')) {
        inputRange[0].value = maxValue - rangeGap;
      } else if (e.target.classList.contains('input--max')) {
        inputRange[1].value = minValue + rangeGap;
      }
    } else {
      progressBar.style.left = (minValue / inputRange[0].max) * 100 + '%';
      progressBar.style.right = 100 - (maxValue / inputRange[1].max) * 100 + '%';
    }
  });
});
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: rgb(107, 216, 107);
}

.slider {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: rgb(42, 138, 42);
}

.slider--body {
  background: rgb(250, 250, 250);
  height: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.slider--progress {
  position: absolute;
  left: 25%;
  right: 25%;
  background: rgb(107, 216, 107);
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.slider--inputs {
  position: relative;
}

.slider--inputs>input {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.slider--input {
  position: absolute;
  top: -2.4px;
  left: -3px;
  height: 5px;
  width: calc(100% + 2px);
  background: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.slider--input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid rgb(42, 138, 42);
  pointer-events: auto;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: rgb(107, 216, 107);
}
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slider--body">
    <div class="slider--progress"></div>
    <div class="slider--inputs">
      <input type="range" class="slider--input input--min" min="0" , max="999999" step="10" value="250000" />
      <input type="range" class="slider--input input--max" min="0" , max="999999" step="10" value="750000" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



So far i tried using getBoundingClientRect to calculate the collision, however I need to set the gap before detecting collision
let div1 = document.getElementById('div1').getBoundingClientRect();
let div2 = document.getElementById('div2').getBoundingClientRect();

function touching(d1,d2){
    let ox = Math.abs(d1.x - d2.x) < (d1.x < d2.x ? d2.width : d1.width);
    let oy = Math.abs(d1.y - d2.y) < (d1.y < d2.y ? d2.height : d1.height);
    return ox && oy;
}

Any ideas to get me into the right path ?


When would the min/max be changed? Are they dynamically set by JS? 2. Why is it an issue if they do change? I assume that either the min/max need to be bigger than the default range, or the range needs to be made smaller if the bounds of the range if it no longer fits in the bounds of the min/max


yes, min and max values are dynamic geneted from backend. and its values are what defines the range. so the range in iteself is dynamic

I'm not sure I see the complication then? Surely the range is just simple subtraction of the values set by the back end?

but the range is not calculated, I need to set up a dynamic range gap between min and max so they dont overlap. if I set the gap at 20px, it would work for a range between 10 and 300, but if the range is between 5 and 30, the gap would look bigger. I'm looking for ideas how to dynamically calculate range gap based on dynamic values min/max/

Ah ok, so the real issue is that you want to stop them overlapping. The description of 'calculating the range' is very misleading. The fix for this would generally be to have no gap and show some input fields which display the selected values. That way users can either click and drag the handles, or type the values in manually. The choice is theirs. This also allows them to explicitly fix the handles if they overlap and they can't grab the one they need.

the solution you described, while it works, it's not the asked requirement. even if you display input to show values as you slide. there is still a need to set a range gap between the min/max handler. is there a way to achieve this ?
